Way to use signal in template expression?
Let say I have
interface Point {
  x:number;
  y:number;
}

@Component(...)
class PointComponent {
  point = signal<Point>({x:0, y:0});
}

Now I can do this in template
@if(point(); as point) {
  <pre> x: {{point.x}}, y: {{point.y}} </pre>
}

But I have used @if as auxiliary control flow block because I can't to introduce template variable other way.
Of course I can do this
<pre> x: {{point().x}}, y: {{point().y}} </pre>

But is there some way to introduce template variable to do it concisely?

I think last way of doing it is pretty common usage. Are you worried about performance because you see function calls in template? Or what? it should be pretty cheap and any other solution avoiding it will not do it faster

@DanyloGudz yes, but now I see, for compiler it won't be the problem to optimize access to reading of signal. But I remember the days when angular community discussed opportunity to introduce ngLet directive in order to solve problems like this. So we will be writing parenthesis)

what problem do you want to solve? directive like ngLet would do 10x more processing work then just call signal getter, you will not get any advantage except for visual satisfaction of not doing a lot of calls in template

@DanyloGudz my proposal is to use something like this @let(point() as point) {...}. Angular compiler can process that block without introducing performance issues.

idk where you did find performance issues, did you do any benchmarking? I think that you overthink about calling signal getter multiple times

@DanyloGudz I didn't say anything about performance issue with calling signall getter, if you can't understand my intention sorry I haven't other words

You could use computed to do this, if you do not prefer if syntax, but @if seems like the least code option
import { Component, signal, computed } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
interface Point {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    @if(point(); as point) {
      <pre> x: {{point.x}}, y: {{point.y}} </pre>
    }
    <pre> x: {{x()}}, y: {{y()}} </pre>
  `,
})
export class App {
  point = signal<Point>({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  name = 'Angular';
  x = computed(() => this.point().x);
  y = computed(() => this.point().y);

  ngOnInit() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.point.set({ x: Math.random(), y: Math.random() });
    }, 2000);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

In Angular templates, you can use the ng-template directive along with the ngTemplateOutlet directive to achieve this
<ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="pointTemplate" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: point() }"></ng-template>

<ng-template #pointTemplate let-point>
  <pre> x: {{ point.x }}, y: {{ point.y }} </pre>
</ng-template>


With the latest version of Angular, you can now use the @let syntax:
@let _point = point();
<pre> x: {{ _point.x }}, y: {{ _point.y }} </pre>

It currently doesn't support naming the variable the same as the field, so you have to be creative here.
